# Series in Ultrametric Spaces

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

For ultrametric $d_v$

> A series $\sum x_n$ is convergent iff $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(x_n)=0$

This is the third part of question, I did first two part which says every trinagle is isocle and every point in circle is centre.

I did not figure out the proof, could you give me some hint?

Comment: Use the Cauchy criterion for series

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Michael in the comments, let $S_n = x_1 + \cdots + x_n$.  You want to show that the sequence $S_n$ converges to something.  I assume you're working in a complete metric space, for example $\mathbb{Q}_p$, so that is equivalent to saying that the sequence $S_n$ is Cauchy, i.e. for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $N$ such that for any $n > k \geq N$, you have $|S_n - S_k| < \epsilon$.  But for any $n > k$, $$|S_n - S_k| = |x_{k+1} + \cdots + x_n| \leq \max \{|x_{k+1}|, ... , |x_n| \}$$ What can you say now?