# if $\sum a_n$ converges, then so is $\sum a_{n_k}$ converges for all subsequence of $a_n$

Tags: calculus, summation

if $\sum a_n$ converges, then so is $\sum a_{n_k}$ converges for all subsequence of $a_n$

**Attempt**:

I think is Proff

if $\sum a_n$ converges then $a_n\rightarrow 0$, so if we take $a_{n_k}$ it must be  $a_{n_k}\rightarrow 0$.

How I can prove that Formally

Comment: It is true that $a_{n_k}\rightarrow 0$, but that does not imply the convergence of the sum.

Comment: Unless we are in ultrametric spaces: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1678753/series-in-ultrametric-spaces

Comment: The conclusion is true for any subsequence $n_k$ if and only if the series is absolutely convergent, i.e. $\sum |a_n|<\infty.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot prove it, since it is false. Let$$a_n=\begin{cases}\frac2{n+1}&\text{ if $n$ is odd}\\-\frac2n&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$Then the series$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\left(=1-1+\frac12-\frac12+\frac13-\frac13+\cdots\right)$$converges, but the series$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{2n-1}\left(=1+\frac12+\frac13+\cdots\right)$$diverges.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, how i can Formally answer?

Comment: Is there something informal in my answer?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes. The use of "$\cdots$". For many students going from that informal expression to a definition of a sequence (piecewise or otherwise) is a struggle. This asker possible wants to know how to define $\left( a_n\right)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ and $\left(n_k\right)_{k\in \mathbb N}$. I'm not claiming your answer is insufficient in some sense, this isn't a criticism of your answer, this is just a reply to your question. Yes, there is something informal in your answer.

Comment: @GitGud I've edited my answer. What do you think now?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos That's up to the asker, I suppose. I'd guess it's good for them.

Answer (score 2):

It is not true. Take the alternating harmonic series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac {(-1)^n}{n}$ which is convergent. However, taking all $a_n$ with an even index gives a divergent series.